# Iterating a function overwrites the dataframe each time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I am converting multiple docx files to a dataframe file. The code works for one document and this leads to the following structure:

```
data = {'Title': ['title first article, 'title second article'], 'Sources': ['source of first article', 'source of second article']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The structure is the result from a function:

```
def func_convert_updates(filename):
    path = os.chdir('C:/Users/docxfiles')
    regex = '\xc2\xb7'
    with open(filename, "rb") as docx_file:
        result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
        text = result.value # The raw text
        text2=re.sub(u'[|•●]', " ", text, count= 0) 
        with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
            text_file.write(text2)

    #followed by many lines of code, omitted here, to create a dataframe

    return df_titles
```

And then I want to analyse multiple docx files so therefore I wrote the following code:

```
list_news= ['docx_file_1', 'docx_file_2.docx', ... etc]

for element in list_news:
    df_titles = func_convert_updates(element)
```

However, this only returns the dataframe of the last element of the list as it overwrites previous output. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean function_convert_docx() instead of func_convert_updates()? If not, is func_convert_updates() a separate function?

Comment: Yes you are correct, made an error in writing this question. The two functions are the same (I've changed it to the correct ones now).

Comment: why not append at each step? `df_titles = []` olutside the loop, then `df_titles.append( func_convert_updates(element))`

Comment: I think what's happening is that you are using the same file name (output.txt) for every element with a write access. Write always overwrite. Try "a" or "w+". Here is a brief overview of different accesses: https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html#:~:text=1%20Python%20allows%20you%20to%20read%2C%20write%20and,ENTIRE%20contents%20of%20a%20file%20More%20items...%20

Comment: I tried to add ```df_titles = []``` and then ```df_titles.append(func_convert_updates(element))``` but this is not working yet. I'll try to create an empty dataframe with the same columns and then to append each dataframe to this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all the DataFrames you created in each loop in the variable `df_titles` you can do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_titles = pd.concat([func_convert_updates(element) for element in list_news], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that if you call your function multiple times you tell `open` to write to `'output.txt'` file, overwriting the file if it exists, with the `'w'` argument. You might want to change that to `'a'` to append to the file, so :

```py
with open('output.txt', 'a', ...
```

Also see
https://cmdlinetips.com/2012/09/three-ways-to-write-text-to-a-file-in-python/